# Blog Posts - Scroll to view more

Tags: posts, pagination, infinite-scroll

I have a page with all my blog posts in it and I have it set to show all my posts on one page. (See screenshot) Now am I looking for away to only show 10 posts at a time and on scroll show more. I see there are plugins like this https://en-ca.wordpress.org/plugins/ajax-load-more/ but this needs a pagination, I do not want a pagination because of SEO reasons. (new SEO errors come up when a new page for the pagination comes up)

Is there away to this with jquery or javascript?

Comment: You want to load all the posts at one time? The loading will slow.

Comment: I am okay with that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load all the posts and hide them exclude 10. If the user scroll to page bottom show more 10.

```js
$('article').each((i, el) => {
   if (i > 9){
      $(el).hide();
   }
});
$(window).scroll(() => {
       if ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.body.offsetHeight) {
          $('article:hidden').first().show();
    }
});
```

Comment: This works great, I am show 2 posts per a row, anyway I can show 2 at a time when scrolling? Right now it looks uneven every time I scroll

Comment: replace to `$('article:hidden:lt(2)').show();`. If the answer helped you, mark its with check.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks